# How do I resolve issue occurred with name mangling even after using extern "C"?

Tags: c++, c, dll, name-mangling, borland-c++

To avoid the problem with name mangling of C++ code I have used the extern "C" in my header file. But, the problem is still persisting "**when I build my dll file using Borland C++ IDE**".

Below is my sample code.

Others.h file

```
#define H_EXPORT WINAPI  

  #ifdef __cplusplus

  extern "C" {

  #endif

  long H_EXPORT RegOpenKeyEx32( DWORD hKey,LPCSTR lpSubKey,DWORD ulOptions,REGSAM   samDesired,DWORD FAR *phkResult);

  #ifdef __cplusplus

  }

  #endif
```

Others.cpp file

```
  #define C_EXPORT WINAPI _export
  //The function has been define like this

  long C_EXPORT RegOpenKeyEx32( HKEY      hKey,
                              LPCSTR     lpSubKey,
                              DWORD      ulOptions,
                              REGSAM     samDesired,
                              PHKEY      phkResult)
  {

   //some code
  }
```

The ordinal value given for that function in def file is

RegOpenKeyEx32      @243

but,after building the dll i has exposed the dll using Dll Export Viewer it's ordinal value is changed to 85 and function name changed to **@RegOpenKeyEx32$qqsp6HKEY__pxcululpp6HKEY__** and the functions are mangled like this

[image]

In the same file i.e, others.cpp only some function names(5 function names) get mangled, remaining function names are same(not get name mangled). I did not understand what the problem is?

Any idea what the problem is please reply ...

Comment: Does others.cpp include others.h?

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes it is others.h include in others.cpp

Comment: You haven't got the extern "C" around the function definition in others.cpp

Comment: Hi guys sorry to trouble you it is due to the mismatch with the parameter types

Comment: So you solved it then :). btw moved the comments to answer so its a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `extern "C"` both for declaration AND definition.

You may modify Others.cpp file as follow

```
#define C_EXPORT WINAPI _export

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
long C_EXPORT RegOpenKeyEx32(HKEY    hKey,
                             LPCSTR  lpSubKey,
                             DWORD   ulOptions,
                             REGSAM  samDesired,
                             PHKEY   phkResult)
{
    //some code
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

For less complex DLLs build by borland this worked for me:

```
#define FX_ENTRY extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#define FX_CALL  __stdcall

FX_ENTRY void FX_CALL exported_function1()
 {
 // do something
 };

FX_ENTRY void FX_CALL exported_function2()
 {
 // do something
 };
```

- well I use BDS2006 which is old but anyway
- I was not able to get around this for more complex DLLs (more then 50 functions).
- even if the names where correct not all functions can be imported
- nor by static import nor by dynamic (via winapi).
- The same goes for DLL function **inplace** renaming by **PE decode/encode** utility
- needed @ inside function name!!! to simulate some ancient mangling style
- usually 2-10 functions from 100 are non-linkable
- does not matter if App which use DLL is build by MSVC++ or borland.
- The only solution is def file but I am not sure how to (if even possible) use def file for dll creation on Borland compilers
- on MSVC++ is easy enough